# SSL operation failed with code, while sending push notification to ios devices

Tags: ios, push-notification, openssl, apple-push-notifications, stream-socket-client

I am trying to send push notifications, to iOS Devices which was working pretty well, but suddenly it started throwing the following error:

> stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL
>   Error messages: error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1
>   alert internal error

I checked with server port 2195 and 2916 both are enabled and double checked the `.pem` file which seems correct too.

I would appreciate if I can get help on the above error.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that the certificate has expired?

Comment: Suddenly, as in all devices at once? Something has changed either on devices either on your server. What are the *OpenSSL* versions used (or if any other cryptography provider please specify the name and version)? Has something updated on the involved parties?

Comment: Either check certification, May be the p12 certificate you are using has been expired or changed of the path of your .pem file is changed

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi you should export Apple push service certificate screen shot given below  and export it, Iam also got same error now fixed by export this certificate.
```

Let me know if you have any clarifications.

[image]